# CSS Grid: Items on column 2 don't seem to want to start from row 1. Why is that?

Tags: css

Basically as the title states. The items in Col 2 on my grid are refusing to start from row 1 on the grid. In my instance, they start from row 4.

Here's my code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.col-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.content-box {
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="content-box col-1">
        <h3>All Content</h3>
        <?php foreach($titles as $title): ?>
            <a href="update.php"><?= $title->headline; ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box col-1">
        <h3>All Products</h3>
        <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
            <a href="update.php"><?= $product->name; ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box col-1">
        <h3>All Services</h3>
        <?php foreach($services as $service): ?>
            <a href="update.php"><?= $service->name; ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box col-1">
        <h3>All Support Links</h3>
        <?php foreach($supportOptions as $option): ?>
            <a href="update.php"><?= $option->name; ?></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<!-- COL-2 -->
    <div class="content-box col-2">
        <h3>Reset Password</h3>
        <form method="post" action="helpers/newpassword.helper.php">
            <label for="currentPass">Current Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="currentPass" id="currentPass">
            <label for="newPass">New Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="newPass" id="newPass">
            <label for="repeatPass">Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repeatPass" id="repeatPass">
            <a href="helpers/newpassword.helper.php" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- ADMIN ONLY -->
    <div class="content-box col-2">
        <h3>Add User</h3>
        <form method="post" action="helpers/adduser.helper.php">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label for="newPass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="newPass" id="newPass">
            <label for="repeatPass">Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repeatPass" id="repeatPass">
            <a href="helpers/adduser.helper.php" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box col-2">
        <h3>Users</h3>
        <p><strong>Admins</strong></p>
        <a href="#">Admin1</a>
        <br>
        <p><strong>Total Users</strong>: 3</p>
        <a href="#">View Userlist</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated with the HTML to see exactly what's going on here.

Aesthetically, it actually works out better than I had originally planned, but I just want to understand why this happened.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to occure in the snippet

Comment: @SuperDJ - How odd! I've never encountered this issue before either. That's why I was so puzzled to see this.

Comment: Is there some additional CSS applied to `col-2`? Maybe from a framework?

Comment: @SuperDJ just raw html and css. No frameworks here. The individual items have the class “col-1” or “col-2”  rather than having a parent div with the col class. Doing it with parent divs would obviously fix the problem seeing as the grid only sees the 2 divs, but I lose out on the flexibility of shifting things around with 2 keystrokes and the grid-gap that way.

Comment: @SuperDJ Just updated the OP with my html. Should've actually done that from the very start. My bad!

Comment: Check out my code pen do you mean this as result? https://codepen.io/justmemaarten/pen/RmwOpa

Comment: @MaartendeWolf - Essentially, I wanted 2 columns a Left and a Right, but I wanted the right column to start on row 1 of the grid instead of row 4 as it does in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It starts on row 4 because you add it after 4 rows. Try the following instead:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.grid-container .grid-container {
  padding: 0;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.col-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.content-box {
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Spans 2 columns */
.col-width-2 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="content-box col-width-2">
          <h3>All Content</h3>
          <?php foreach($titles as $title): ?>
              <a href="update.php"><?= $title->headline; ?></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="content-box col-width-2">
          <h3>All Products</h3>
          <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
              <a href="update.php"><?= $product->name; ?></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="content-box col-width-2">
          <h3>All Services</h3>
          <?php foreach($services as $service): ?>
              <a href="update.php"><?= $service->name; ?></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="content-box col-width-2">
          <h3>All Support Links</h3>
          <?php foreach($supportOptions as $option): ?>
              <a href="update.php"><?= $option->name; ?></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- COL-2 -->
    <div class="content-box col-2">
        <h3>Reset Password</h3>
        <form method="post" action="helpers/newpassword.helper.php">
            <label for="currentPass">Current Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="currentPass" id="currentPass">
            <label for="newPass">New Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="newPass" id="newPass">
            <label for="repeatPass">Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repeatPass" id="repeatPass">
            <a href="helpers/newpassword.helper.php" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- ADMIN ONLY -->
    <div class="content-box col-2">
        <h3>Add User</h3>
        <form method="post" action="helpers/adduser.helper.php">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label for="newPass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="newPass" id="newPass">
            <label for="repeatPass">Repeat Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="repeatPass" id="repeatPass">
            <a href="helpers/adduser.helper.php" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box col-2">
        <h3>Users</h3>
        <p><strong>Admins</strong></p>
        <a href="#">Admin1</a>
        <br>
        <p><strong>Total Users</strong>: 3</p>
        <a href="#">View Userlist</a>
    </div>
</div>
```